# W10 windows hiding in mutliple applications

Tags: windows-10

When I take notes from a PDF file into e.g. Word document, whenever I click on the PDF, the Word windows automatically hides, and I have to get it back on screen by the taskbar. This process is quite painful if you have say multiple Word documents opened at the same time.

Is there a way to undo windows hiding when I switch to another windows underneath ? For example, can I make the first (top) windows transparent ?

Comment: One way to quickly alternate between two (or more) windows is the Alt+Tab - option. Or you could use the snap-option - or just don't completely overlap them, so you can always "grab" the window beneath on a corner. That said, inactive windows are not hiding, the now-active window simply is in front of all inactive ones. If I misread your question and Win10 really hides your windows (meaning they wouldn't appear even if you minimise or close the now-active window), then I'm sorry. Some of the tips shown on action here: https://www.gcflearnfree.org/windows10/tips-for-managing-multiple-windows/1/

Comment: _the now-active window simply is in front of all inactive ones_ That's my point, so you didn't misread! Is there any option to make the inactive one transparent for example ?

Comment: Not as far as I know - perhaps there is some program for such a trick on the market. I don't see how your feature would be any good: You now have a transparent window in front and you want to write in the inactive window behind it - how do you know without trial&error where you are now and where you are writing? What is the disadvantage of browsing through windows e.g. via Alt+Tab - or what is the advantage of the transparent window over Alt+Tab? Because to me, it sounds like the worst idea one could have in terms of sorting windows.

Comment: @flolilolilo it would be much quicker than Alt+Tab, especially with multiples windows opened (~1 second faster, which translates to several minutes per day) + more concentration since the documents are always opened in front of you !

Comment: Can't see that, as you have to specify *where* you want to do *what* **every time**. The whole concept of GUI is: as displays are two-dimensional, the most important ("active") thing has to be in front of all the less important ("inactive") things so one can see it. So just making it transparent won't do the trick - it would also need to be behind the active window when it isn't.
What about the Snap-feature that stib and I (sort of) elaborated?

Comment: Snap functionality is a great tip ! I'll certainly use it from now on.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the windows-left arrow or windows-right arrow keyboard shortcut, also known as Aero Snap.

That will make the active window take up half the screen aligned to the left or right edge of the screen, and in Windows 10 it lets you then choose another window to display along side it, called Snap Assist. It's very useful if you're working between two documents or applications.

It was introduced in Windows 7, and windows 10 introduced Snap Assist. More info [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/06/04/arrange-your-windows-in-a-snap/#4ghBeXobrR3BQ5RA.97).